# Htaccess redirect all to http except for subdomains on one domain

Tags: .htaccess

I have a multi-website CMS system and I am redirecting all traffic to https. I have one domain, however, that has lots of subdomains that I don't want to redirect to https. I tried a lot of options but can't seem to get this right, here is what I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This does the redirect for all sites to https.

I have a lot of subdomains that I don't want to redirect to https. How can I do it?

Comment: @al.g. please add **Edit Summary** _briefly explain your changes (corrected spelling, fixed grammar, improved formatting)_  for an edit

Comment: @ravisachaniya The reason I decided to reject your edit was that you introduced a new spelling mistake (sub-domain), added unnecessary backticks around the domain and left two other mistakes in the post untouched. (a lots & 'however'). What is left is the indentation that you fixed, but compared to the other things I decided there were enough reasons to click "Reject & edit" instead of "Accept & edit". Sorry if I offended you, it was not intended. What I do is solely for the purpose of improving the site.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add condition for that sub domain in the rule.

Check the below code :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mywebsite. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Hope this will helps you!

Answer (score 0):

To redirect a specific domain to `https` you can use the following Rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

# check if the host header is "www.example.com .com" or "example.com"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
# check if the https is off (scheme is http)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# redirect the request to https
RewriteRule  (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

This will 301 redirect `www.example.com` and `example.com` to `https://HTTP_HOST` .

Clear your browser cache before testing this.